# Perl TCP Socket programming vs C recv() function. Do I need to keep track of bytes received?

Tags: c, perl, sockets, tcp

I am familiar with TCP/IP programming in C but am somewhat new to Perl. In C you need to write a loop around your recv() statement since you are not guaranteed to get all your data from the remote server in one recv() statement.

i.e.

```
while(Size != 0)
 {
  Status = recv(Socket, Buffer, Size, 0);
   Buffer = Buffer + Status;
   Size = Size - Status;
  }
```

Pretty much all the examples I have seen in Perl show just printing what you get from the socket without keeping track of the bytes you received.

i.e.

```
my $new_sock=$sock->accept();
while(<$new_sock>)
 {
  print "$_\n";
 }
 close($sock);
```

So, does Perl somehow make sure you get all your data without having to count your bytes?

If the answer is no, can someone point me to an example of Perl TCP code that does keep track like my C example above?

Answer (score 1):

The `< >` (readline function) is rather high level and great for convenience.

`IO::Socket` supports a `recv` method.

As `IO::Socket` inherits from `IO::Handle` you may also be interested in the `read` or `sysread` methods that closely emulate the low-level C interface for which you're looking...

Answer (score 1):

Your example in C is wrong. `recv` returns `-1` if it failed to read because of an error and `0` on eof (e.g. shutdown of the connection), so you need to exit the loop once `status<=0`. A similar behavior is with `recv` in Perl: it returns undef on error and the buffer will be `''` on eof. And you get the number of bytes read by checking the size of the buffer (`length($buf)`).

But, in your example you don't use `recv`, but `<>`, which is similar to `getline`, e.g. buffered I/O. And like buffered I/O in C it will try to read until the requirement (e.g. full line read) is met or eof occured.

So for buffered I/O similar to `fread`,`fwrite` and `getline` use `read`,`write` and `<>`, for unbuffered I/O use `recv`,`sysread` and `syswrite` which behave the same as in C `recv`,`read` and `write`, e.g. read/write as much is possible but don't block unnecessarily.

Comment: Hi, yes I removed the couple of lines of code that handle the -1 and 0 returns. I just wanted to show how I was handling the returned lengths from recv() in C. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the C example, you read a fixed number of bytes. In the Perl example, you read until the stream is closed. The two snippets are different because they are perform different tasks.

They don't even use the same tools. The C example uses `recv(2)`, while the Perl example uses `read(2)`.

Mind you, you should never read until the stream is closed without validating that you have received the complete stream by some other means. If the connection teardown packets arrive in the wrong order, you can end up missing the end of the stream without knowing it. (Used to happen to me a lot using FTP clients back in the 90's.) The Perl example is not guaranteed to get all the data (though it usually will).